# Fetching live location in odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I am are trying to get a exact live location of our users based on IP address but i can't able to fetch the exact location, Field fetching only a server IP location not users location. Please assist

Comment: You can't get live location unless the client keep posting the real coordinates back to you. It required app permission to share this location. The best bet is to use the IP geolocation like IP2Location and query it from the user IP address.

Comment: @MichaelC. Im already using IP geolocation, but its not fetch exact location. Please assist